# scheduled posts are showing when I am logged in

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, posts

I have posts and they are upcoming, but they are visible in site. So when I am logged in admin panel, that post's single page is ok, but when I logged out in that case it redirects to error 404 page. What's the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: i think you check htaccess

Comment: please check condition in your page template of single.php or page.php...

Comment: here is my htaccess code, # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress @bhavesh vala

Comment: I checked, see just a loop, no condition @vrajesh

Comment: htaccess is ok wait... i will check

Comment: ok will wait @bhavesh vala

Comment: currently what permalink have you set from admin side?

Comment: Permalink is Post name @vrajesh

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/logout-from-admin-dashboard-sends-to-404-error-page

Comment: seems in this topic issue resolved by updating wordpress version, but I am running latest version, my single page isn't working only for scheduled posts and in case when I am logged out @vrajesh

Comment: check the post is publish or not

Comment: checked with this code `<?php if ( get_post_status ( $post->ID ) == 'private' ) { echo 'private';} else { echo 'public';} ?>` and it prints public @bhavesh vala

Comment: ok check your function.php find the  `wp_logout` add action and replace  `add_action('wp_logout','go_home');
function go_home(){
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();
}`

Comment: I put it but no result, what should do this? @bhavesh vala

Comment: are you using any paid theme ? @aidaghazaryan

Comment: no, twentyfourteen wordpress theme @bhavesh vala

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83498/discussion-between-bhavesh-vala-and-aidaghazaryan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, just added this to my functions.php and future posts are showing in single.php:

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'show_future_posts');
function show_future_posts($posts){
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;
   if(is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0)
   {
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);
   }
   return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this add filter `the_post` filter

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post